# Edit animated gif header loop value using Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I'd like to change the loop header value of a gif animation, specifically [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unfasor.gif):

[image]
[attribution: Gonfer at en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unfasor.gif)

I am attempting to use the [python imaging library, PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/1.1.6), and have come up with the following based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540390/1461850).

```
import PIL as p
a=p.Image.open('Unfasor.gif')
loop = a.info['loop']
a.save('out.gif',loop=10)
```

This re-saves the gif but it is no longer animated.

Note the value of the loop attribute is presently 0:

```
>>> a.info
{'duration': 0, 'version': 'GIF89a', 'loop': 0, 'extension': ('NETSCAPE2.0', 27L)}
```

How can I export as a working animated gif, with a non-zero loop value? I am open to using other libraries.

*Note. The reason that I am doing this is that [I'd like to put the image into a powerpoint-2007 presentation](https://superuser.com/questions/818939/import-gif-animation-into-ms-powerpoint-2007) and have [seen suggestions that this loop value is a limiting factor](https://superuser.com/a/79581/217142).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, using PowerPoint 2011, this image works as is.

Note that it is not animated during 'edit' mode, but when in 'slide-show' mode it appears animated just as it does above.

Which version of PowerPoint are you using? and have you tried it in slide-show mode yet?

I expect the non-animation in edit mode is on purpose. I could see that getting very tedious while you were doing slide layout :)